# How to load URL with parameters in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm using Ruby and the Nokogiri gem to scrape.

When I scrape data from a particular website, with an example URL

```
http://www.foo.com/bar.php?s=stuff&sub=morestuff
```

I end up getting  the HTML from the page `http://www.foo.com/bar.php` in Nokogiri.

How do I get the HTML from the page with the PHP query?

The code I'm using is:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'Nokogiri'

URL = "http://www.foo.com/bar.php?s=stuff&sub=morestuff"
data =  Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ? You got it already in the "data" variable ... You can use `wget` (or `curl`)  - assuming a *nix-box - to check whether its actually a GET-request with these parameters. Also, for seeing what will happen, disable JavaScript on your browser and inspect what happens when you visit the URL (usually you can do that hitting F12).

Comment: Suggestion for title (if I got you correctly): How to load URL with parameters in Nokogiri
Note that there is a difference between GET and POST parameters.

Comment: felix, thanks for the reply. If I look in the "data" variable all that is in there is all the HTML from the base link, not what I get in my browser when I visit the first link. If I disable javascript, and visit the URL with the queries, it just loads the bar.php. what does that mean? Sorry for my ignorance, Im going to read up on wget and curl

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't ask poor questions. Research, try, then write good questions. Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: It looks like the site is redirecting your request, which drops the parameters. Since you didn't give us the real URL we can't help test that, so you'll need to use a HTTP client like curl, and tell it to not follow redirects, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Use uri and create url with params

```
require 'uri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

uri = URI.parse('http://www.foo.com/bar.php')
params = { :s => "stuff", :sub => "morestuff" }

# Add params to URI
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)

html = open(uri) do |f|
  charset = f.charset 
  f.read
end

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html, nil, charset)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying!!! This doesn't seem to work. doc still contains the html from before everything is loaded

Comment: Does the page have like a <form action="bar.php" method="post"> and input tag?
If so, you use 'net/http' instead of 'open-uri' because open-uri not support POST request.

Comment: I don't see anything like that in the source. Is there a way to tell if its a GET or POST query? Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: It's a GET request by default. If there's a form it could use a POST or GET parameter.